Adonis.js 6 Error Dropping Constraints: "relation does not exist"
I am working on a project using Adonis.js 6 and I am facing an issue when trying to migrate an old database structure to a new one. My goal is to remove certain tables that are bound by constraints. I've set up a list of these tables and their corresponding constraints as follows:
const dropConstraints = {
  api_tokens: ['api_tokens_user_id_foreign'],
  conversation_logs: [
    'conversation_logs_ip_id_foreign',
    'conversation_logs_uuid_id_foreign',
    'conversation_logs_version_id_foreign',
  ],
  logs: ['logs_version_id_foreign'],
  qa_tests: ['qa_tests_version_id_foreign'],
} as {
  [key: string]: string[]
}

To remove the constraints I've tried using this.schema.alterTable:
await this.schema.alterTable(table, async (tableBuilder) => {
            tableBuilder.dropForeign(constraint)
          })

And executing SQL commands:
for (const table of Object.keys(dropConstraints)) {
  if (await this.schema.hasTable(table)) {
    const constraints = dropConstraints[table];
    for (const constraint of constraints) {
      await this.schema.raw(`ALTER TABLE "${table}" DROP CONSTRAINT "${constraint}"`);
    }
  }
}

Despite the check to confirm if a table exists (this.schema.hasTable), I receive an error for every table indicating that the relation does not exist (for both methods):
ALTER TABLE "api_tokens" DROP CONSTRAINT "api_tokens_user_id_foreign" - relation "api_tokens" does not exist

I have also tried specifying the schema explicitly:
ALTER TABLE "public"."api_tokens" DROP CONSTRAINT "api_tokens_user_id_foreign"

But, I still get a similar error stating that the relation does not exist.
Question: What might be causing these errors, and how can I successfully drop these constraints?

Direct SQL Command:

I iterated over each table and its corresponding constraints to execute a SQL command for dropping each constraint.
I used the following code snippet for this operation:
for (const table of Object.keys(dropConstraints)) {
if (await this.schema.hasTable(table)) {
  const constraints = dropConstraints[table];
  for (const constraint of constraints) {
   await this.schema.raw(`ALTER TABLE "${table}" DROP CONSTRAINT "${constraint}"`);
  }
}
}




Table Existence Verification:

To avoid attempting to drop constraints from non-existent tables, I included a check using this.schema.hasTable(table) to ensure the table exists before trying to drop any constraints.


Specifying Schema:

Given the persistence of the error, I attempted to prepend the table name with the schema in the SQL command:
await this.schema.raw(`ALTER TABLE "public"."${table}" DROP CONSTRAINT "${constraint}"`);





What I Was Expecting:

Successful Constraint Removal: After confirming a table's existence, I expected the SQL command to successfully drop the specified constraints without any errors.
No Relation Errors: Since the existence check was supposed to filter out non-existing tables, I did not anticipate seeing errors related to non-existent relations.

Despite these measures, the errors persisted, leaving me unsure of the underlying cause of the issue and how to resolve it.
